# Sign up for Google Apps and Google Analytics via API or similar

Tags: google-analytics

I cannot figure out how to sign up for Google Apps and Google Analytics with a new domain via API or similar.

I have an automated CMS where users can create their own sites etc. and when they do it would be nice to automatic be signed up for Google Apps and Google Analytics etc...

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  The GA API does not let you do things like that.  It only lets you read/retrieve certain info from GA.